# making program that checks if you have entered a valid username & pw that're saved in separate files, but only one of each works

Tags: python

```
import sys, os, time
```

simple modules

```
f = open('profile001.txt','r')
user1 = f.read()
f.close()

f = open('profile001p.txt','r')
user1p = f.read()
f.close()

f = open('profile002.txt','r')
user2 = f.read()
f.close()

f = open('profile002p.txt','r')
user2p = f.read()
f.close()
```

that code opens and reads the username and password documents

```
usr = input('please enter your username : ')
while usr != user1 or usr != usr2:
    usr = input('that username does not exist, please try again : ')
if usr == user1:
    pw = getpass.getpass('Please enter password : ')
    if pw != user1p:
        sys.exit()
    if pw == user1p:
        os.system('cls')
        process = input('welcome!')
if usr == user2:
    pw = input('Please enter password : ')
    if pw != user2p:
        print('incorrect')
    if pw == user2p:
        os.system('cls')
        process = input('welcome!')
```

that code asks what the name and pw is, but whenever i input the user2 or user2p it tells me that the username is not recognised although it is in and when i print usr2 or user2p it correctly prints it... i think it may be because of the WHILE loop, as i am a beginner and do not know much about while loops.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `user2`? I can't see it defined before `while usr != user1 or user2:` which does not do what you think it does (you would need `while usr != user1 or usr != user2:`)

Comment: @roganjosh I assume `user1` and `user1p` werent meant to be duplicated above considering the file names, but that `or` is definitely a problem

Comment: @Nick re-reading I think it's a typo after `f = open('profile002.txt','r')` and that should in fact be assigned to `user2` rather than `user1 = f.read()`. In a more general sense though, I'm not sure I'm clear on the intended flow, especially with `sys.exit()` everywhere...

Comment: @roganjosh and the `while`s instead of `if`s

Comment: @roganjosh i have changed the first while statement and fixed the typo, but i am still having the same problem... thank you for the help so far :)

Comment: @NickA I have now changed the unneeded while statements but i am having the same problem still... thank you for your help so far :)

Comment: For one thing, `while usr != user1 or usr != usr2` should be `and`: as it is now that condition is always true if the two users differ.

Comment: @Chris thank you, i will try that now

Comment: thanks all, code is now working! i appreciate the help :)